# How can I organize my Angular app folders like a Java package?

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, angular, systemjs

How to organize Angular 2 app folder structure like Java packages?

Consider the following project layout:

```
app
 |_model
 |_component
 |_service
```

I would like to import `foo.service.ts` from *service* to `bar.component.ts` in *component*. But as far as I know, Angular 2 import supports only relative paths like `/../service/`, which seems very clunky solution.

Is there a way to refer folders with absolute bath from *root folder*, like with Java packages?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2016-06-01**

using `npm install typescript@next` you can already use this function

I assume that your tree looks like this:

```
node_modules
 |_@angular
 |_rxjs
app
 |_model
 |_component
 |_service
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

You should add in your tsconfig.json the following lines:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "app/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

then you can reference your modules like you do with regular @angular/rxjs modules

```
import { MyService } from 'service/MyService';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Note: webpack needs also the following lines in webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
        'node_modules',
        'app'
    ]
}
```

Comment: As you already mentioned, this is in discussion since last september (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039). I'm just surprised they didn't think about it before. Going with "../../../" is so cumbersome. 
Thanks for your answer. TS@2.0 is coming soon ; Beta has been released 6 days ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, it should be present soon with Typescript 2.0

Look here
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039